# How do I create a hidden field programatically?

Tags: 7, entities

I've got a module that is creating fields programatically, all working so far. The code is below. This may be useful as-is if you are trying to create checkboxe fields from an array of values:

```
    /**
     * Helper function to create fields for workflow approvers
     *
     */

    function _create_approval_fields($approverRolesClean){
      $fieldPrefix = 'wf_';

      // TODO: If an existing field is removed, delete it.

      foreach ($approverRolesClean as $approverRole) {
        $cleanRole = preg_replace('/[^a-z]/', "", strtolower($approverRole));
        $fieldName = $fieldPrefix.$cleanRole;
        if (!field_info_field($fieldName)) {
          $field = array(
            'field_name' => $fieldName, 
            'type' => 'list_boolean',
            'widget' => array(
              'type' => 'options_onoff',
              'settings' => array(
                'display_label' => '1',
              ),
            ),
            'settings' => array(
              'allowed_values' => array(
                '0' => 'No',
                '1' => 'Yes',
                ),
              ),
            );
          field_create_field($field);
        }
        //Hardcoded:
        if (!field_info_instance('node', $fieldName, 'contenttype')) {
          $instance = array(
            'field_name' => $fieldName, 
            'entity_type' => 'node', 
            'label' => 'Approved by ' . $approverRole, 
            //Hardcoded:
            'bundle' => 'contenttype',
            'widget' => array(
              'type' => 'options_onoff',
              'settings' => array(
                'display_label' => '1',
              ),
            ),
          );
          field_create_instance($instance);
        }
      }
    }
```

I set the value of the fields outside the Edit screen - so they never need to show there. I'm sure there is a settings parameter that I can add to hide it, but not sure where to find the doc. I don't think no_ui is what I need.

Otherwise I can use the form api to hide it at render time, but that doesn't seem as elegant.

Thanks,

Jack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a regular Field API field, you can easily hide it with

[hook_field_access](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_access/7)

e.g:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_access
 */
function mymodule_field_access($op, $field, $entity_type, $entity, $account) {
  if ($field['field_name'] == 'field_wf_admin' && $op == 'edit') {
    // Only allow admins to edit field value
    return user_access('administer nodes', $account);
  }
  return TRUE;
}
```

Alternatively, there's the [field_extrawidgets](http://drupal.org/project/field_extrawidgets) module for hidden and readonly Field API fields

Answer (score 1):

I don't follow the example 100%, but to answer the question - in D7 you can set `'#type' => 'hidden', '#value' => 'foo'` or just do `'#my_custom_key' => 'my custom value'` and it will be available to you in the submit handler (or elsewhere, such as hook_field_attach_submit()).

Comment: Thanks Charlie, the thing is I use the field as a checkbox in a different place. The content is boolean (checkbox makes sense). I just want to hide it on the edit screen. In the interim, I've just used a hook_form_alter() to hide them, that may be the best solution.

Comment: Simple and functional! Two useful pieces of info for `'type' => 'hidden'` fields: its [Drupal API specs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7.x#hidden) and a [way to render them with `id` attribute](https://www.drupal.org/node/988294#comment-5862764).