# How to programmatically hide field from display?

Tags: 7, entities

I want to reproduce programmatically hiding of a field that can be obtain by Manage Display -> Format -> (hidden)

URL: admin/config/people/accounts/fields.

Field I want to hide is added by OG module. Probably. Machine name: og_user_user.

I found one [solution](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/50246/how-do-i-create-a-hidden-field-programatically) based on hook_field_access but I need to find other.

This [solution](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/51731/how-to-hide-field-from-entity-display-view-programmatically) doesn't help me too.

Comment: Where you want to hide it?

Comment: And why exactly solution you found is not good for you? And what is it in the first place? If you won't tell us, possibly someone will provide it to you again - waste of his time, waste of your time.

Comment: @Mołot question edited. Client want to hide it once (preferred in custom module install file). Using hook is just unaccepted. At least for now.

Comment: What do you mean by "hide it once"? After cache clear it should be shown again? Or what?

Comment: @Mołot using this hook is redundant, or I am wrong? Code in install file is invoked only once.

Comment: @drupality yes, it is. So? If code to SHOW things is in hooks, and thus run every cache clear or so, then hidding things once will accomplish only what it says - hide it until next hook run. That's how Drupal was designed, if you don't agree with it's design, all you can really do is not to use it.

Comment: @Mołot ok I agree, but there is someone above me.

Comment: If he is telling you to do things that are impossible in Drupal, by design, we can't really help you.

Comment: Anyway I am pretty sure that there is other solution.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is pretty damn simple. I forgot about [field_update_instance](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.crud.inc/function/field_update_instance/7) function.

To get data for passing to this function there is a need of debug: [field_ui_display_overview_form_submit](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field_ui!field_ui.admin.inc/function/field_ui_display_overview_form_submit/7)

where all Manage Display forms are submitted.

I end up using custom drush command after all custom modules are installed